# Find duplicate entries in two different lists

Tags: search, vimdiff

I have two different lists of words and I want to make sure that they have no mutual duplicates. In other words, none of the words in list A can be in list B and vice versa. They must be mutually exclusive word lists.

Both lists are guaranteed to be sorted alphabetically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a vimscript list or a bunch of words in a file? If the latter, what format are they in? (One word per line? Separated by commas?)

Comment: Are these lists of words contained in separate files? If so, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470260/how-to-find-duplicate-lines-across-2-different-files-unix. For me this question as it stands is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution in my mind is to use `comm` utility.

List A:

```
comm -2 -3 a.txt b.txt > a.txt
```

List B:

```
comm -1 -3 a.txt b.txt > b.txt
```

You can do this inside of Vim with the filter command, `:!`. e.g. `:%!comm -2 -3 % b.txt`

For more help see `man comm` and `:h :range!`

Answer (score 1):

A “visual” solution would be to arrange two windows, each with one of the two buffers you want to view (e.g. `vim a b` then `:vs | next`).

Then do `:windo diffthis` to turn on the diff mode.

---

Untested, but you might be able to `vimdiff a b`.

Answer (score 1):

I answer in the case you wish to test the intersection between two `|List|` expressions, and not comparing text. In that later case others have already provide good answers.

Linear O(N) algorithms won't be efficient once implemented in vimscript as they would require using `:for` which has terrible performances. Functional O(N²) implementations are likely to be the fastest with current versions of Vim.

For instance, in that case I'd use the following function from my [vim script library](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib)

```
function! lh#list#intersect(list1, list2) abort
  let result = copy(a:list1)
  call filter(result, 'index(a:list2, v:val) >= 0')
  return result
endfunction
```

Comment: I like that you addressed the vimscript possibility, but could you provide some references for the comments on performance? Im curious to read more about it

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. Unfortunately I don't have numbers to provide, as I haven't keep them. I did experiments with lists of up to tens of thousands elements. Often I've observed a clear win for functional API (`map()` and `filter()`) over traditional iterative algorithms (`:for`, `:while`). Everything started with the need to process and analyse a lot of tags. In the end, I've rewritten several functions from my `autoload/lh/list.vim` file, just to speed up what could be. Note that I don't exclude that with greater numbers of elements, lower complexity is likely to win.